# Enumerations object name

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

enum color {
    black=1, blue, green, cyan, red, purple, yellow, white

} colors;

int main(){
   color mycolor;
   mycolor = blue;

   cout << mycolor;

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any usage for object name colors? And could I be able to print out the name of any of these color by using Enumerations or I only can print out the constant number which each of color corresponding to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any usage for object name colors?

Yes: if you want a global variable of type `color`, you can define it right after the declaration of the `enum color`.

> could I be able to print out the name of any of these color by using Enumerations or I only can print out the constant number which each of color corresponding to?

No, you would not be able to print the names of `enum` members given an enum value, unless you build a system in your own code through which you would be able to "decode" constants back to string representations. One common way to do that is creating a parallel array of string literals:

```
#define TO_STR(X) #X

const char* color_names = {"none", TO_STR(black), TO_STR(blue), TO_STR(green), ...};
```

As you can see, inability to convert an enum to string does not apply to enum constants known at compile time: you can use [a preprocessor trick to stringify them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1514031/335858).

Another common way of mapping enum values to string is using a `std::map<color,std::string>`. It is similar to a parallel array in that you need to initialize it manually, though. It works much better for "flag" enums, i.e. enums that do not use sequential values.

Comment: But what's the purpose to use numerations since I define it as color but i print out a branch of number on the console?

Comment: @Ming The purpose is improving your program's readability: `set_color(cyan)` is a lot more descriptive than `set_color(4)`.

Comment: Could you please list a example?

Comment: @Ming You've got a pretty good example in your question: your program that uses `color` is much more understandable to outside readers than one that uses numbers both externally (i.e. in printing) and internally (i.e. in the code).